# Json deserialize string with 2 arrays

Tags: c#, json

I have to Serialize a string with two list collections as JSON string.

```
 public class Product {
   public string  Name {get;set;}
 };

 public class Product2 {
   public string Age { get; set; }
 };

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   List<Product> mitems = new List<Product>();
   List<Product2> mitems2 = new List<Product2>();
   mitems.Add(new Product { Name = "John" });
   mitems2.Add(new Product2 {Age = "28" } );
   var objects = new { mitems, mitems2 };

   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects);
   var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);
 }
```

In the last line, I am getting an exception `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object`

Comment: He's serializing an *array of (array of product mixed with product2)* in fact

Comment: @Cid, no it's a dictionary of arrays of product and product2. Ouch

Comment: Rather an anonymous class containing a list of product and product2. Still nothing to do with a `List<Product>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, one is you can deserialize as `dynamic` or you can define a root object for your final json.

```
var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

and casting to your object lists:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
List<Product2> products2 = new List<Product2>();

foreach (var item in Items.mitems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    products.Add(((JObject)item).ToObject<Product>());
}

foreach (var item2 in Items.mitems2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item2.Age);
    products2.Add(((JObject)item2).ToObject<Product2>());
}
```

output :

```
John
28
```

or

```
class RootObj
{
    public List<Product> mitems { get; set; }
    public List<Product2> mitems2 { get; set; }
}

var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(json);

foreach (var item in Items.mitems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}

foreach (var item2 in Items.mitems2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item2.Age);
}
```

output:

```
John
28
```

Outputs for both deserialization methods:

[image]

Comment: This example doesn't return me anything

Comment: I added the outputs. Both examples correctly deserializes the string.

Comment: Your first example looks very easy. But how can i send Items into 2 separated lists?

Comment: Do you want to extract mitems and mitems2 from deserialized dynamic object?

Comment: I added how to extract data to two seperate list.

Comment: Thank very helpfull example. It's the only example that it works. So there is not code which it will place them directly in each list? I need to add them manually right?

Comment: If you need to seperate lists (not in one root object) you have to do it manually. In my last example, RootObj contains seperate list if you want to have strictly typing you can use that approach.

Comment: Using your second example doesnt returns me anything from lists foreach (var item in mitems)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Name );
            }

Comment: I updated my answer, I guess now you can use second approach too.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of an anonymous object probably you would want to create a model to hold this like

```
public class MyModel
{
  public List<Product> products { get; set; }
  public List<Product2> products2 { get; set; }
}
```

In `Form_Load`

```
MyModel model = new MyModel
{
  Products = mitems,
  Products2 = mitems2,
}

var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
```

per your comment, if you want to iterate through Products then

```
foreach(var data in Item.products)
{
  MessageBox.Show(data.Name);
}
```

Comment: How can i use  foreach (var item in products )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Name);
            }

Comment: foreach(var item in Items.Products)  { MessageBox.Show(item.Name); }

Comment: @user6453020 see update in answer. That would have been an easy find for you

Comment: I am getting error form model doesnt contain definition for Products. If i will change Products with products then i am taking error inside forach loop, null exception

Answer (score 2):

You can't deserialise objects to a `List<Product>` because it isn't a `List<Product>` it's a new anonymous type with two properties

Change

```
 var objects = new { mitems, mitems2 };
```

To

```
 var objects = new List<Product>(mitems);
 objects.AddRange(mitems2);
```

Also Product2 is not a product

You also need to change

```
 public class Product2
```

To

```
 public class Product2 : Product
```

in order to add it to a list of Product

Comment: If i will follow your example, in deserialize i am getting two values instead of one, first one is null  foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Age);
            }

Comment: @user6453020 The first item won't have an Age since it's not a Product2.

Comment: I just want to add each array in each specific list

Comment: @user6453020 Then use Rahul's answer and serialise them to seperate lists

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(json)["mitems"];
Console.WriteLine(((JArray)item).ToObject<IList<Product>>());
```

Edit: I rephrased my answer

Fiddler Example : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ItMClb

Comment: Your example looks easy but i am geting error +  Exception Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Core.dll

Comment: can you check again?

Comment: JArray cannot be found\

Comment: Add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to your references